# Firebase make 3 requests at a time MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, firebase-authentication, android-viewmodel

So I am starting to build a chat app and now I am at the registration screen.

Every time I press the login button,the request is sent only 1 time,like it should do.
The problem starts when I get in return the error message(e.g "Your password is incorrect"),after I get the error,I am pressing the login button again with the same wrong password,and I get Log error that I made but its showing 3 times, at the same time and firebase tells me that I have made too many attempts....

This is what I have done:

ViewModel:

```
    private val _authState by lazy { MutableLiveData<AuthState>(AuthState.Loading) }
    val authState: LiveData<AuthState> = _authState

fun loginUser(emailAddress: String, password: String) {

        if (!isEmailAddressValid(emailAddress)) {
            _authState.value = AuthState.AuthError("Invalid email")
            return

        } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
            _authState.value = AuthState.AuthError("Password field can't be empty")
            return

        } else if (emailAddress.isEmpty()) {
            _authState.value = AuthState.AuthError("Email field can't be empty")
            return

        }


            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->

                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    _authState.value = AuthState.Success
                } else {
                    task.exception?.let {
                        _authState.value = AuthState.AuthError(it.localizedMessage)
                    }
                }

            }
    }
```

This is the Activity:

```
binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener {

            val emailEditText = binding.emailAddressEditText.text.toString()
            val passwordEditText = binding.passwordEditText.text.toString()


                registerLoginViewModel.loginUser(emailEditText, passwordEditText)

                registerLoginViewModel.authState.observe(this@LoginRegisterActivity, object : Observer<AuthState?> {
                    override fun onChanged(loginState: AuthState?) {
                        when (loginState) {

                            is AuthState.Success -> {
                                hideLoadingScreen()
                                Toast.makeText(this@LoginRegisterActivity,"Welcome Back!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                Intent(this@LoginRegisterActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                                finish()
                            }

                            is AuthState.AuthError -> {
                                hideLoadingScreen()
                                Log.e("Error:","Error Message: ${loginState.message}") // This line returns 3 times after the second attempt
                                Toast.makeText(this@LoginRegisterActivity,loginState.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                            else -> {
                                showLoadingScreen()
                            }
                        }

                    }
                })
        }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Just a note: `LiveData.observe(...)` doesn't need to be in any kind of listener. You can observe in `onCreate()` of Activity ahead of API call. As it is in your code now, you're adding one new observer every time your click listener is called.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @rupinderjeet! 

Comment: @rupinderjeet Agree with Frank van Puffelen. You should add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LiveData.observe(...)` doesn't need to be in any kind of listener. You can observe in `onCreate()` of Activity ahead of API call. As it is in your code now, you're adding one new observer every time your click listener is called.

Here's a small example:

```
class FruitsActivity : AppCompatActivity {

    private val binding by lazy {
        FruitsActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    } 

    private val fruitsViewModel by viewModels<FruitsViewModel>() 

    @Override
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Observe from fruitsViewModel.fruits
        fruitsViewModel.fruits.observe(this) { fruitList ->
            // Use `fruitList` in your adapter
        }

        // Fetch fruits on tap of a button
        binding.loadFruitsButton.setOnClickListener {
            fruitsViewModel.fetchFruits()
        }
    }
}

class FruitsViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _fruits = MutableLiveData<List<Fruit>>()
    val fruits: LiveData<List<Fruit>> = _fruits 

    fun fetchFruits() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // `someRepository` can be anything that calls an API 
            // or queries a database to get the required data.
            // Repository Pattern + Coroutines recommended
            val fruitList = someRepository.fetchFruits()

            // if needed, perform any filters or modifications to `fruitList` here

            // set the result data on LiveData
            _fruits.value = fruitList
        }
    }
}
```

So, this is what happens:

- Activity launches.
- Initializes `binding` and `fruitsViewModel`.
- Adds an `Observer` on `fruits` from `fruitsViewModel`
- Sets click listener on a button to load fruits
- When you tap the button, `fruitsViewModel` fetches fruits and sets result data on LiveData (`_fruits`).
- LiveData finds its observers and notifies them about new data.

Let me know if you have any questions or if there's something wrong. I wrote the code directly in this text-field, so there might be a dot, comma or colon misplaced or missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer !